# How to style the color of the sort icon through a theme override for MUIDataTable?

Tags: sorting, material-ui, styling, mui-datatable

I am needing to override the color of the sort icon in a `MUIDataTable`. I am currently able to override basically everything else except this.

Through the debugger view I have tried quite a bit and cannot seem to touch on this icon.

This is what I am currently trying to call to get to it

```
MuiTableSortLabel: {
  icon: {
    color: "#eee",
  },
  iconDirectionAsc: {
    color: "#eee",
  },
  iconDirectionDesc: {
    color: "#eee",
  },
},
```

I have this called as well within the overrides -

```
MuiSvgIcon: {
  root: {
    color: "#eee",
  },
},
```

The sort icon is currently the default color (black) as this code does nothing to style the icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l47CJ.png)

Update work around: This does not satisfy the overrides but is called in styles-

'@global': {
    'div > span > svg > path': {
      fill: '#eee'
    },

},

Answer (score 2):

Based on @anthony-z answer this worked, just "& path" instead of "& svg":

```
const StyledTableSortLabel = withStyles(theme => ({
    icon: {
        backgroundColor: grey[500],
        '& path': {
            fill: '#eee'
        },
    }
}))(TableSortLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll probably do it for you.

```js
MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
  sortAction: {
    '& svg': {
      color: "#eee" // or whatever you need
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not work. MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      fixedHeader: {
        color:'#eee',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },
      sortActive: {
        color:'#eee',
      },
      sortAction: {
        '& svg': {
          color: "#eee" 
        },
      },
    },

Comment: Driving me kind of crazy :) Thank you for your response!

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, it's this library right? https://www.material-ui-datatables.com/

Comment: Or is it the default Material-UI table?

Comment: Yes I am calling it through overrides in a theme like so - const getMuiTheme = () => createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      fixedHeader: {
        color:'#eee',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },
      sortActive: {
        color:'#eee',
      },
      sortAction: {
        '& svg': {
          color: "#eee" 
        },
      },
    },

Comment: Using MUIDataTable <MUIDataTable
            title={""}
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
          />

Comment: Through debugger I was able to touch on almost every other element of the table but for some reason this one alludes me.

Comment: This is what I'm using to get an understanding of your setup. That bit I posted should have worked given it's the same version. https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-customize-styling-vt2ov?fontsize=14 You might have to make the window wider to make it be a horz table.

Comment: Again for more context, are you using v2.0.0? I updated the pen to v2.2.0 and it still seems to work.

Comment: import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables"; I believe so as its the same import. I am new to material ui and react. Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I think I'd have to see your code base to be able to help you more. Or you'd have to show me the markup of one of your header cells with the sort arrow. I can't seem to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I see that. I think I am using the latest version that is offered by react/material UI - yours works but mine not so much.

Comment: If you want to put your code into a codepen, I'll help you further. Sorry I couldn't get you anywhere.

Comment: Yes using the latest 4.01 version of material ui

Comment: Do you have a repo with your code? Or you could even update your post with the whole component if you want.

Comment: I did it with fill instead of color. Thanks for the css reference!

Answer (score 0):

To override the sort icon color, try

```
overrides: {
  MuiTableSortLabel: {
    active: {
      color: 'green' // your color here
    }
  }
}
```

If you need help with custom style overrides in general, you can check out the example here: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-styling/index.js.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know how to override the search area as well? The line that text is input to highlights blue when focused and is default black. I have been unable to figure this out as well. I can post another questions if not.

Comment: I just realized it did not render properly and this solution doesnt seem to work. With the latest version Material ui

Comment: You shouldn't be using the latest version of material ui with mui-datatables, as they are not fully compatible and you will likely run into issues. I wouldn't go higher than the library recommends which is 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

try this it has worked for me

```
MuiTableSortLabel: {
    root: {
        '&$active': {
            color: **<your color>**
            '&& $icon': {
                color: <your color>
            },
        },
    },
},
```